# Switching Variables in L'Hopital, Series, Limits

Tags: limits, derivatives

[image]

My Question is from lines 2 to 3. How did you get from lim x to infinity to 
limit t approaching zero from the positive?

Comment: You make the substitution, $x=1/t$.

Answer (score 1):

The following substitution was used: $\quad\displaystyle \;x = \dfrac 1t.\;$

But this substitution requires that we determine to what value $t$ approaches as $x\to \infty$:

And so we note that, as $\;x \to \infty$, $\;\;x = \dfrac 1t \implies t = \dfrac1x  \to 0^+,\;\;$ so we can now rewrite our limit as the limit of a function of $t$: 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\,x\ln\left(1+\frac 2x\right)\;\;=\;\; \lim_{t\to 0^+}\,\frac{\ln (1+2t)}{t}\tag{type $\,\frac 00$}$$

And so now $L'Hopital is used.